# Google Sheets CONCATENATE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Good afternoon. Get help from the Google Sheets experts.
With the CONCATENATE function, separators are displayed if the cell is empty. Help hide three ; delimiter.
Link to table and screenshot attached....................
[image]
[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13VLB4KpUBQkTc61wJ22kBNsrQQK1PTNjbvlp4_F4ye4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the formula you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TEXTJOIN()` with option ignoring blank. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ";1;MAP(A2:A7;B2:B7;LAMBDA(x;y;TEXTJOIN(" ";1;x;y))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=textjoin("; ",true,byrow(A2:B7,lambda(j,textjoin(" ",true,j))))
```

Result:

[image]